# SQL DELETE / UPDATE with subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using the following SELECT query as a subquery, I would like to update my table so that the duplicates are removed. Specifically, I would like to delete records with ID 2 and 5.

DATA:

```
id  | email
-------------------------
1   | @.example.com
2   | @example.com
3   | @test.com
4   | @.example.net
5   | @example.net
```

```
SELECT COUNT( M.id ),
    REPLACE( REPLACE( M.email, '@.', '' ), '@', '' ) AS addr
FROM wblist WB
    LEFT JOIN mailaddr M ON M.id = WB.sid
    WHERE WB.wb = 'B' AND M.email LIKE '@%'
GROUP BY addr HAVING COUNT( M.id ) > 1;
```

```
 count |          addr
-------+-------------------------
     2 | example.com
     2 | example.net
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also you show values from one table, but your question refers to two.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample SQL refers to two tables, so it seems to have nothing to do with your actual question.

If you had one table, the logic (in most databases) would be like this:

```
delete from data
    where id > (select min(d2.id)
                from data d2
                where replace(replace(d2.email, '@.', '' ), '@', '' ) = replace(replace(data.email, '@.', '' ), '@', '' )
               );
```